# How to get this overlap effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blend-modes

**I don't know if similar question has been asked before, but can anyone help me to turn this:**
[image]

**...into something like this:**
[image]

I was following a tutorial but it didn't show what effects and tools were being used. Here's the link, if it helps: [Visit](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bq2K5OZBMo5/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link)

Comment: Use the Transparency palette to change the blending mode of the overlapping objects to 'Screen' or 'Lighten'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Draw shape

2- Apply''Screen' from 'Transparency' on the overlapping parts.

3- experiment with Freeform gradient.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]